# Student who got MAX marks in subject

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am facing one issue in getting student name who scored MAX marks in each subject.

Here are my tables below

[image: Student Names]
   [image: Student Marks]

First one is `Student` table having `STUD_ID , STUD_NAME` & Second one is `MARKS` table having `STUD_ID, SUBJECT, MARKS`.

Can you help me in getting query to retrieve `STUD_NAME`, `SUBJECT`, `MAX(MARKS)`.
I having tried below but facing issue in getting `STUD_NAME`.

```
select SUBJECT, MAX(MARKS) as Highest
from MARKS inner join STUDENT
ON STUDENT.STUD_ID = MARKS.STUD_ID
GROUP BY SUBJECT
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTE with `RANK()` function. Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms176102(v=sql.110).aspx):

Example:

```
WITH ordermarks AS (
    SELECT [STUD_ID],[SUBJECT],[MARKS], RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [SUBJECT] ORDER BY [MARKS] DESC) AS rn
    FROM marks
)
SELECT [STUD_NAME],[SUBJECT],[MARKS]
FROM ordermarks om
JOIN Students s ON s.[STUD_ID]=om.[STUD_ID] AND rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use `DENSE_RANK()` and `CROSS APPLY`.

I tested [below query on a 440K record set](http://pastebin.com/FavF2C5c) *(link to pastebin)*  and it runs in .01 sec.

```
select     stud_name as [Student Name]
        , [subject] as [Subject]
        , marks     as [Max Marks]
    from dbo.Marks m
 cross apply (select   s.stud_id
                     , s.[subject]
                     , s.marks
                     , dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY s.[subject]  ORDER BY s.marks desc) AS drnSub 
              from dbo.student s 
            ) s
                 where s.stud_id = m.stud_id 
                     and s.drnSub  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pawel Tags for your reply and it's perfect . 
One more way here

```
SELECT STUD_NAME,SUBJECT,MARKS
FROM [STUD_TEST] S
JOIN [MARKS_TEST] M ON S.STUD_ID = M.STUD_ID
WHERE M.MARKS =
(SELECT MAX(MM.MARKS) FROM [MARKS_TEST] MM GROUP BY 
    MM.SUBJECT  HAVING MM.SUBJECT=M.SUBJECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER function to return only the "best" row per subject:

Query 1:

```
SELECT Name, Subject, Marks
FROM(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Marks DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.Student
)X
WHERE rn = 1
```

Results:

```
| NAME | SUBJECT | MARKS |
--------------------------
|    f |       C |    46 |
|    g |       H |    20 |
|    c |       M |    30 |
```